# Regional settings

Tags: regional-settings

I have two questions in regards time stamp in SharePoint online:

1. If someone change the regional settings under his or her account what would be the difference? For instance in site collection the regional setting has been set for Singapore and someone using the same SharePoint environment but lives in Germany?
2. If I create a date column, would the date be different in different countries with different time zones?

Answer (score 0):

All dates are stored as UTC in SharePoint and displayed according to the regional settings of your SharePoint site.

Comment: Thanks Callum. Do you know if the users change the time preference in Delve or Office365? Does this affect SharePoint?

Comment: The date is shown according to the regional settings of the individual SharePoint site, I don't believe anything will else will override that setting.

Comment: Thanks again for your message, does this means if I live in the US and someone else lives in China and we are using the same SharePoint site, and the regional settings are set to the US, the user in China will see the local time under the date column?

Comment: It would appear as the US time, is my understanding.

Comment: According to Microsoft, users can change their time zone under their profile which will over right the site collection time zone. We have done that; however, all the time zones remain the same. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that is the case but it can take a while for a user profile change to take affect. If it takes too long or doesn't take affect then you might want to open a support ticket with Microsoft.